# How to obtain the colModel name from iCol index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid event handler that receives the iCol as a parameter. I need to know how to obtain the name specified in colModel for that given iCol.

For example given the following jqGrid event handler:
onSelectCell that receives rowid, celname, value, iRow, iCol

How can I get the colModel name associated with the iCol index?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us you have grid with id="list". Then you can use either

```
var cm = $("#list")[0].p.colModel;
```

or documented

```
var cm = $("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam','colModel');
```

to get a reference to the array `colModel`. So

```
cm[iCol].name
```

will get us the name of the corresponding column.